# Angular 2 pop up modal

Tags: .net, angular, modal-dialog

I'm working in .net C# Angular 2 environment.  I'm having issue with something that should be easy.  Just trying to do a simple popup modal dialog box.

I can't see to put the html statement in verbatim and have the text in this message as i'd prefer, but I'll  just state that I have a  'mat-raised-button' in the .html with "onclick = paymentDetails()"

and the corresponding typescript .ts file:

```
public paymentDetails() {
    console.log("changeFlagStatus");
}
```

Should be simple, in fact essentially same code exists all over the application.  It's just when i add this new button i get the runtime error:

"Uncaught ReferenceError: paymentDetails is not defined
       at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (detail:1)"

Is there something special i need to do to add a new button into the mix?

Answer (score 1):

You trigger a method on click like this:

```
<mat-raised-button (click)="paymentDetails()></mat-raised-button'>
```